# Why is the call to array_view::synchronize() so slow?

Tags: c++-amp

i've started experimenting with C++ AMP. I've created a simple test app just to see what it can do, however the results are quite surprising to me. Consider the following code:

```
#include <amp.h>
#include "Timer.h"

using namespace concurrency;

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    uint32_t u32Threads = 16;
    uint32_t u32DataRank = u32Threads * 256;
    uint32_t u32DataSize = (u32DataRank * u32DataRank) / u32Threads;
    uint32_t* pu32Data = new (std::nothrow) uint32_t[ u32DataRank * u32DataRank ];

    for ( uint32_t i = 0; i < u32DataRank * u32DataRank; i++ )
    {
        pu32Data[i] = 1;
    }

    uint32_t* pu32Sum = new (std::nothrow) uint32_t[ u32Threads ];

    Timer tmr;

    tmr.Start();

    array< uint32_t, 1 > source( u32DataRank * u32DataRank, pu32Data ); 
    array_view< uint32_t, 1 > sum( u32Threads, pu32Sum );

    printf( "Array<> deep copy time: %.6f\n", tmr.Stop() );

    tmr.Start();

    parallel_for_each( 
        sum.extent,
        [=, &source](index<1> idx) restrict(amp)
        {
            uint32_t u32Sum = 0;
            uint32_t u32Start = idx[0] * u32DataSize;
            uint32_t u32End = (idx[0] * u32DataSize) + u32DataSize;
            for ( uint32_t i = u32Start; i < u32End; i++ )
            {
                u32Sum += source[i];
            }
            sum[idx] = u32Sum;
        }
    );

    double dDuration = tmr.Stop();
    printf( "gpu computation time: %.6f\n", dDuration );

    tmr.Start();

    sum.synchronize();

    dDuration = tmr.Stop();
    printf( "synchronize time: %.6f\n", dDuration );
    printf( "first and second row sum = %u, %u\n", pu32Sum[0], pu32Sum[1] );

    tmr.Start();

    for ( uint32_t idx = 0; idx < u32Threads; idx++ )
    {
        uint32_t u32Sum = 0;
        for ( uint32_t i = 0; i < u32DataSize; i++ )
        {
            u32Sum += pu32Data[(idx * u32DataSize) + i];
        }
        pu32Sum[idx] = u32Sum;
    }

    dDuration = tmr.Stop();
    printf( "cpu computation time: %.6f\n", dDuration );
    printf( "first and second row sum = %u, %u\n", pu32Sum[0], pu32Sum[1] );

    delete [] pu32Sum;
    delete [] pu32Data;

    return 0;
}
```

Note that `Timer` is a simple timing class using QueryPerformanceCounter. Anyway, the output of the code is the following:

```
Array<> deep copy time: 0.089784
gpu computation time: 0.000449
synchronize time: 8.671081
first and second row sum = 1048576, 1048576
cpu computation time: 0.006647
first and second row sum = 1048576, 1048576
```

Why is the call to synchronize() taking so long? Is there a way how to get around this? Other than that the performance of the computation performance is amazing, however the synchronize() overhead makes it unusable for me.

It is also possible that i am doing something terribly wrong, if so, please tell me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Function synchronize() is probably taking so long because it is waiting for the actual kernel to complete its work.

From [parallel_for_each from amp.h](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/parallelforeach-From-Amph-Part-1.aspx):

> Please note that the parallel_for_each executes as if synchronous to the calling code, but in reality, it is asynchronous. I.e. once the parallel_for_each call is made and the kernel has been passed to the runtime, the [code after the parallel_for_each] continues to execute immediately by the CPU thread, while in parallel the kernel is executed by the GPU threads.

So, measuring the time spent in parallel_for_each is not particularly meaningful.

EDIT: The way the algorithm is written, it won't benefit much from GPU acceleration. The read of source[i] is non-coalesced, and so it will be almost 16x slower than a coalesced read. It is possible to coalesce the read by using shared memory, but it is not quite trivial. I'd recommend reading up on GPU programming.

If you just want a simple example that demonstrates the utility of C++ AMP, try [matrix multiplication](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/Matrix-Multiplication-With-C-AMP.aspx).

Of course, the performance you'll observe also greatly depends on the model of you GPU hardware.

Comment: So it means that the actual computation on GPU takes so long? If so, is there a way to speed it up so it will at be as fast as CPU?

Comment: I edited the answer to explain why the GPU computation is slow.

Comment: Thanks! Will look into it more.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Igor's response on your specific algorithm, please note that there are multiple incorrect aspects of the way you are measuring C++ AMP performance in general (no runtime initialization exclusion, no discarding of initial JIT, no warmup of data, and the already pointed out assumption of p_f_e being synchronous), so please follow our guidelines here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nativeconcurrency/archive/2011/12/28/how-to-measure-the-performance-of-c-amp-algorithms.aspx

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you for your reply. I have already found the MSDN blog you are linking to and i'm studying all the amazing examples you have there. Thanks!